# Re-evaluate attributes passed to directive after scope variable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a series of element generated within an `ng-repeat` :

```
<tr ng-repeat="index in elements">
  <td ng-click="doSomething(index)" my-tooltip tooltip="isInBasket(index.id) && 'REMOVE FROM BASKET' || 'ADD TO BASKET'" ></td>
</tr>
```

The directive `MyTooltip` is expecting a value passed to the `tooltip` attribute.
This will work the first time, that means when the ng-repeat is executed. The tooltip will have a value of "REMOVE FROM BASKET" if the element is already in basket and a value of "ADD TO BASKET" otherwise.

The function is defined as follow:

```
$scope.isInBasket = (id){
  return _.contains($scope.basket, id)
}
```

Now, other parts of my code will change `$scope.basket`, so I supposed that the `isInBasket` would be re-evaluated whenever the `$scope.basket` changed and as a consequence change the value passed to the `tooltip` attribute.

The directive

```
angular.module("tooltips", [])
    .directive("myTooltip", ($parse, $rootScope, $state){
      return {  
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 999,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          tooltip = scope.$eval(attrs.tooltip);
          // .... 
        }
      }
    })
```

But this doesn't work, I'm quite sure I'm doing something wrong or I am missing something.

Comment: I made an edit to also include the directive

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating an Isolated scope?, if yes then you need to declare in your scope:
{
tooltip: '&'
}

I think the problem is that you are binding to a boolean, that as not permuttable breaks the double binding, but to be honest not sure how are you doing the tooltip directive

Try with your directive:

```
angular.module("tooltips", [])
  .directive("myTooltip", ($parse, $rootScope, $state){
    return { 
      scope: { tooltip: "=" } //you could try also "&"
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 999    
    }
})
```

Ok, and if you try to assign the value like:

```
var tooltip = {dock: scope.$eval(attrs.tooltip)};
```

or
    var tooltip = element.scope()[attrs.tootip];

I mean I know in binding is very important do it against an Object.

If that doesnt help you can bind it with a watch, that should do it:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
  var tooltip = element.scope()[attrs.tootip];

  scope.$watch(function () {
    return scope.attrs.tooltip; // i dont know what changes in your app
  }, function() {
    return  tooltip();
  }, true);
```

Comment: I can't use an isolated scope. And by the way using this method won't evaluate the expression passed in the `tooltip` argument

Comment: Sorry..none of your solutions seems to work for me. It's not easy to understand once and for all how to manage parameter passed to directives..

Answer (score 0):

use `tooltip="{{isInBasket(index.id) && 'REMOVE FROM BASKET' || 'ADD TO BASKET'}}"`

please see below

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.elements = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "banana"
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: "pear"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "apple"
  }]


  $scope.basket = [];
  $scope.basket.push($scope.elements[0].id)
  $scope.isInBasket = function(id) {

    return _.contains($scope.basket, id)

  }

  $scope.doSomething = function(item) {

    if (_.contains($scope.basket, item.id)) {

      $scope.basket = _.without($scope.basket, item.id)

    } else {
      $scope.basket.push(item.id)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
tr {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.*" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="lo-dash@*" data-semver="2.4.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  Basket : {{basket | json }}
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="index in elements">
          <td ng-click="doSomething(index)" tooltip="{{isInBasket(index.id) && 'REMOVE FROM BASKET' || 'ADD TO BASKET'}}" style="padding-left:150px">
            {{index.id}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, made an edit, `tooltip` is an attribute passed to a directive